# Does fitting a model transform categorical to dummy variables automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty straightforward question:

I want to fit a regression model. I have already let pandas know that these variables are categorical. Sample code:

```
bikes_reg['month'] = bikes_reg['month'].astype('category')
```

Do I need to create dummy variables, or will the model create them automatically when I fit it?

What is the general rule of thumb? Do I need to create dummy variables every time I want to use a categorical variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `astype('category')` helps python understand the following :

- A string variable consisting of only a few different values. Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save some memory
- The lexical order of a variable is not the same as the logical order (“one”, “two”, “three”). By converting to a categorical and specifying an order on the categories, sorting and min/max will use the logical order instead of the lexical order

However to feed categorical data into a model , it needs to be numerical(if it's string) and normalized.

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder to normalize the labels

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit([1, 2, 2, 6])
    LabelEncoder()
>>> le.classes_
    array([1, 2, 6])
>>> le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6]) 
    array([0, 0, 1, 2]...)
```

Alternatively , you can also use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` technique as well

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My variables are already encoded as numeric values so i suppose i do not need to change them.

I will create dummy variables before fitting a model from now on.

Comment: Alright.Would be nice if you could accept it as answer